# How to get get the least amount of space between the chapter title and the top margin?

Tags: chapters

I need to have a 3cm gap between the top of the page and the chapter title. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm, tmargin=3cm,
bottom=3.5cm, left= 3.2cm, right=3.7cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=nature]{biblatex}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\addbibresource{uni.bib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge ##}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3pt}{7pt}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Introduzione}{\chapheadtopskip}{\vspace*{30\p@}}{\vspace*        {25\p@}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\Introduzione}{\chapheadbelowskip}{\vspace*{7\p@}}{\vspace*            
{25\p@}}{}{}
\makeatother



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{plain}



\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\addbibresource{uni.bib}


\urlstyle{same}
\newenvironment{dedica}
{\clearpage           % we want a new page
\thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
\itshape             % the text is in italics
\raggedleft          % flush to the right margin
}
{\par % end the paragraph
\vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
\clearpage           % finish off the page
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you tried to incorporate all of the solutions at the same time.  Do you really need fancychap and titlesec?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that in my thesis the professor doesn't want the division in chapters, so if i remove them i get "Chapter 1", and then the title of the chapter.
My goal is to get only the title of the chapter without "CHAPTER 1"

Comment: If you use document class article instead of report, there are no chapters.  Or just use `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! In the end i've changed the class from report to book, and then i've used \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} etc. from \etoolbox package 

I hope that won't compromise anything in the dissertation when i'll print it.

Comment: @robonoff please don't edit titles to indicate things like "SOLVED", you can mark a question as solved by accepting an answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions.  If the solution is currently in a comment you can ping auser and invite them to write their comment(s) as an answer, or if you have found your own solution you can write up your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @DaiBowen thank you so much! I am new to this. I'll do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code with `titlespace*` defined in `titlesec`. This package should be sufficient to format chapters. Negative space in the second argument will depend on document settings.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[
  bindingoffset = 1cm,
  top = 3cm,
  bottom = 3.5cm,
  left = 3.2cm,
  right = 3.7cm,
]{geometry}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-25pt}{40pt}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Sample text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much